# Run Oracle Instant Client in Docker container

Tags: docker, webforms, containers, windows-container, oracleclient

I have a web application built using .NET 4.8, with a data access layer implemented as a class library (not an API). I have dockerized the application using a Windows container, and now I need to connect it to an Oracle database installed on a separate environment. I know that I need an Oracle client (version 19) to enable communication between the application and the database, but I'm not sure how to set this up in a Docker environment. Can anyone provide steps or guidance on how to do this? I have researched some resources, but have not found clear instructions for my specific setup.

Comment: the same way you'd install it on the docker operating system without docker

Comment: I understand that is similar to installing it on a regular operating system. However, I have encountered some issues trying to install the client in the container. I tried copying the Oracle instance to the container and unzipping the files, but I haven't been able to find or create a command to install it in silent mode. Additionally, someone suggested copying the installed version from Windows files and adding the environment variables, but this did not work for me. Do you have any specific guidance or steps? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Review [Docker for Oracle Database Applications in Node.js and Python](https://blogs.oracle.com/opal/post/part-1-docker-for-oracle-database-applications-in-nodejs-and-python) which has samples and also has links to Oracle's Dockerfiles that install Instant Client. The steps are likely to be similar on Windows: you unzip and make sure PATH is set to include the unzipped directory.

Answer (score 1):

This has been discussed in the Oracle GitHub repo: https://github.com/oracle/docker-images/issues/494